# :before element with float:left causing overflow

Tags: html, css, css-float

My container has a list of items with `display: inline-block` and a `::before` element that uses `float:left`. This is causing the last item to overflow the container in specific cases, like this:

[image: Container overflowing]

The floating element is depicted here using a dashed border. I'm following [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/hexagons-and-beyond-flexible-responsive-grid-patterns-sans-media-queries/), so I'm unable to change the floats and inline-blocks to more modern solutions like Flexbox and Grid.

I've tried adding clearfixes everywhere, with no success. Help?

Here is a working fiddle, just resize the output panel until you reach the overflow point:

```css
body {
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.main {
  background-color: teal;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  transition: height 500ms linear;
}

.container>div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: initial;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  width: 1.75rem;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed #DDD;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 3.5rem;
  height: 3.5rem;
}

.item-inner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 0.125rem solid chocolate;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1289324739794735104/mQoHcZfq_400x400.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1289324739794735104/mQoHcZfq_400x400.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1289324739794735104/mQoHcZfq_400x400.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1289324739794735104/mQoHcZfq_400x400.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1289324739794735104/mQoHcZfq_400x400.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1289324739794735104/mQoHcZfq_400x400.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1289324739794735104/mQoHcZfq_400x400.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1289324739794735104/mQoHcZfq_400x400.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: in that tutorial there is a section called "fighting the overflow" talking about this: https://css-tricks.com/hexagons-and-beyond-flexible-responsive-grid-patterns-sans-media-queries/#aa-fighting-the-overflow

Comment: You are correct. The tutorial says there is no way to stop the container from overflowing except adding some padding to the bottom, which will cause an empty row to show up at some times. I guess that's better than overflowing...

Comment: In your output, the images are stacked one below another, not in a cross order. is it what you wanted?